# StackApps thumbnail tooltips show HTML encoded titles

Tags: bug, tooltips, stackapps, html-entities

When hovering over a thumbnail, a tooltip appears showing the title of the question. However, if the title contains special characters, the tooltip displays the HTML entities instead:

[image: StackApps post with apostrophes in its title]

[image: StackApps post with double quotes in its title]

Comment: I totally missed where I had to look for. Confirmed.